# How do I get a list of embassies and emails from this website?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose I wanted to get a list of the embassy names and emails from this list:

https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/united-states/

How would I do this?

Comment: This is too broad to answer.

Comment: Check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/doc)

Comment: What have you tried? There are different python libraries  to scrap data from websites: [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html), [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: @Nabin, for the website specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, Use the below code to get the embassy names and country names from the website in a list. Understand the below code and try to extract the emails.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/united-states/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
country = tree.xpath('//div[@class="posts-container col-md-6"]/h2/text()')
embassy = tree.xpath('//div[@class="posts-container col-md-6"]/ul/li/a/text()')
print(country)
print(embessy)
```

Output:

```
country:
['Belgium',
 'Afghanistan',
 'Albania',
 'Andorra',
 'Algeria',
 'Antigua & Barbuda',
 'Angola',...]

embessy:
['Honorary Consulate of Belgium in Phoenix',
 'Consulate General of Armenia in Los Angeles',
 'Permanent Mission of Afghanistan to United Nations',
 'Consulate General of Afghanistan in Los',...]
```

[image: see this image]

Comment: Where do you find the part after the `//div[@class="posts-container col-md-6"]`?

Comment: you should inspect the website which you are trying to scrap, there you will find what part is required for you. I have updated my answer with the inspect image, hope it helps.

Comment: That's helpful in understanding, thanks, but the problem is that the email is not displayed on the homepage.